# Positioning with after

Tags: html, css, web, layout, position

I watched from 11:30-16:00 [Frontend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfNUJXY3uGg&list=PLu0pRheOFLkEmnlzsKsEjapldwlXd18Ba&index=3). As a result

```
    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h2 class="title title--purple"><span>Live Auctions</span></h2>
    </div>
```

```
    .title {
        font-family: 'Oxanium',
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 64px;
        line-height: 130px;
        color: #F5FBF2;
        position: relative;

        &:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 0;
          transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-40%);
          background: #8613A5;
          width: 110px;
          height: 110px;
          border-radius: 50%;           
        }

        span {
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 2;   
        }
    }

    .title-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

produces the following screenshot

[Live Auctions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/386MB.jpg)

How properties

```
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-40%);
```

allow you to highlight the letter L with a lilac circle, as in the screenshot? Show it in a picture.

I want that someone help me with layout.

Comment: Can you give us additional info of what are you trying to achieve.? Try to put your code using snippet here or try codepen.io and paste the codepen link here so we can see the results.

Comment: @clarkf SO asks that code be within the question as external sites may either disappear or get debugged rendering them useless for future readers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Initially, the top left of the circle is the same as the top left of the text block (block is highlighted yellow). Note, that `line-height: 130px` makes the block height much greater, than text height.

```css
.title {
  font-family: 'Oxanium', font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    left: 0;
    /* transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-40%); */
    background: #8613A5;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  span {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-wrapper">
  <h2 class="title title--purple"><span>Live Auctions</span></h2>
</div>
```

- After `top: 50%` (50% is relative to the text block height) the circle is positioned vertically, so it's upper point is in the middle of the text block.

```css
.title {
  font-family: 'Oxanium', font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    /* transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-40%); */
    background: #8613A5;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  span {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-wrapper">
  <h2 class="title title--purple"><span>Live Auctions</span></h2>
</div>
```

- After `transform: translateY(-50%)` (50% is relative to circle height) the circle is shifted vertically, so that it's center is located at previous upper point location
- `translateX(-40%)` shifts the circle horizontally, so that it's moved to the left 40% of circle width.

Comment: It's seems to be real.

Comment: Why do author use `top: 50%` and `translateY(-50%)` at the same time when you can only do `translateX(-40%)` at once?

Comment: @hpwebsearch This is a common pattern: in the first operation, 50% signifies the middle of the parent block, and in the second, it's the middle relative to the circle. The `top: 50%` shifts the top edge of the circle to the center of the parent block, while `translateY(-50%)` moves the top edge of the circle to the center of the circle itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your `title` class. I put your code below so we can see the output using `run snippet`. So what are you trying to achieve?

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.title {
     font-family: 'Oxanium';
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 64px;
     line-height: 130px;
     color: #f5fbf2;
     position: relative;
}
 .title:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-40%);
     background: #8613a5;
     width: 110px;
     height: 110px;
     border-radius: 50%;
}
 .title span {
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;
}
 .title-wrapper {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="title-wrapper">
        <h2 class="title title--purple"><span>Live Auctions</span></h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: See Yaroslav Sergienko's answer.